# shell script to check file in multiple directories

Tags: shell

I was wondering in case I could do the following, better than what I have.

Objective: Identify files with the same name in the directory tree. 
I do not have any knowledge if there would be any duplicate file or the location/name of such files.

Expected output: List the files with the location.

Input provided: path of top directory for search.

My algorithm:

1. list all file in the target directory (I have used find  -name "*.*")
2. List1: sort the file names
3. List2: Uniquify files names
4. Diff lists from step 2 & 3 to get the repeated file
5. extract the location from step 1.

I am not limited to shell. Simplistic solution in any scripting language is welcome.

regards

Srisurya

eg. directory, in this path file f0 is present in d1 and d2, which need to identified.

d1/f0

d1/f1

d1/d2/f2

d1/d2/d3/f4

d2/f0

d2/f5

More Details:
Sample Directory:

```
temp/
|-- d1
|   |-- d2
|   |   `-- f3
|   |-- d3
|   |   `-- f3
|   |-- f1
|   `-- f2
`-- d4
    |-- d5
    |   |-- f2
    |   `-- f6
    |-- f4
    `-- f5


> find temp/ -type f -follow -print | sed 's;.*/;;' | sort -u > ~/tmp/12
> find temp/ -type f -follow -print | sed 's;.*/;;' | sort -n > ~/tmp/11

> diff ~/tmp/11 ~/tmp/12
3,4d2
< f2
< f3

> find temp/ -name f2
temp/d1/f2
temp/d4/d5/f2

> find temp/ -name f3
temp/d1/d2/f3
temp/d1/d3/f3
```

I want to simplify this process. Any help would be appriciated. 
Please let me know in case you need further details.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal. Duplicate name is enough for you? What about same name but different content? Provide some more information. It will help to get better answer.

Comment: The idea is to identify if a file with same name is present in different hierarchies. Some files have parameters which would be linked and files with same names but different contents may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following code creates hash table to keep track of duplicate files. You can modify the code as per your requirement.

P.S: Only Bash version >4 supports `declare -A`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare hashtable. -A is for associative array
# This hash table will contain filename as key and filepath as value
# filemaps["filename"] = filepath1, filepath2,...
declare -A filemaps

while read fpath
do
# get the basename from filepath
fname=$(basename "$fpath")

# Check if file already exists in hashtable
if [[ "${filemaps[$fname]}" != "" ]] 
then
    # if file is already exists in hashtable, add the
    # duplicate path in its value
    filemaps["$fname"]=${filemaps["$fname"]},$fpath
    continue
fi

# Map the filepath with filename
filemaps+=(["$fname"]="$fpath")
done < <(find $1 -type f)

echo "----> Printing Results <-----"

for i in "${!filemaps[@]}"
do
   echo "Filename  : $i"
   echo "Exists in : ${filemaps[$i]}"
done
```

Result

```
 $ ./test.sh /var/tmp/xxxx/
 Filename  : x.tar.gz
 Exists in : /var/tmp/xxxx/1/x.tar.gz
 Filename  : index
 Exists in : /var/tmp/xxxx/.git/index,/var/tmp/xxxx/1/var/tmp/xxxx/.git/index
 Filename  : file with spaces
 Exists in : /var/tmp/xxxx/file with spaces
 Filename  : x
 Exists in : /var/tmp/xxxx/x,/var/tmp/xxxx/1/var/tmp/xxxx/x
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/directory -name "file_name"
```

Comment: yes please add some explanation of your code showing what it does and how it solves the problem - this will help others who see your answer in thef future

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)